# .htaccess point folder to sub-folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have found  lots of .htaccess pointing tuts for subfolder to root (domain TLD) but not a first level foder to a second level subfolder.
Scenario:
I need to have my .htacces to show the (www.)example.org/folder/ URL, but to use all the resources as it would be (www.)example.org/folder/sub-dir/
So, how do I write the .htaccess in the SiteRoot so that this subfolde "/folde/" point to "/folder/sub-dir/" without any exceptions to resources inside /sub-dir/.

Please help me get out of the mud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(sub-dir(?:/.*)?)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^folder((?!sub-dir)/.*)?$ /folder/sub-dir/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanl you. Can you please explain the Rules? because is only showing the local resources (HTML only) but not the resources under the sub-dir like sub-dir/js sub-dir/images etc. the page is parsed as pure html.

Comment: Can you check your page in Firebug and let me know which pages are causing 404 to you

Comment: It seams that each and every CSS, JS, IMAGES are getting 404 and leaped to the main domain page showing a GET 200 in the FireBug.